# ограничение области поиска geocode-maps

Tags: yandex-geocoding-api

Необходимо ограничить область поиска прямого геокодирования с использованием geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x.
Из [документации](https://yandex.ru/dev/geocode/doc/ru/request) можно понять, что для того что-бы ограничить область поиска необходимо использовать следующие параметры:
**rspn** - ограничивать ли область поиска. Здесь все понятно.
**ll** - Долгота и широта центра области поиска. Здесь тоже вроде понятно, однако не понятен формат передачи координат.
**spn**  - Протяженность области поиска. Здесь вообще ничего не понятно. Говорится о двух значения, которые являются разницей максимальными и минимальными значениями широты и долготы.

**Вопрос:** Необходимо ограничить область поиска страной Россия. При этом в результатах необходимо получить все что попадает область где находится пользователь на первых позициях выдачи.

**PS** так же из выше упомянутой доки видно что есть параметр callback о нем не сказано ничего. Что это за параметр и как им пользоваться?

Comment: Если у вас и так есть адрес вида «Россия, Владимирская область, Петушинский район, Покров, улица Ленина, 31», он и так будет найден в России. Параметр ll задаётся в формате (долгота, широта), это есть в документации и видно в примерах. Параметр spn — количество градусов вокруг точки ll, где нужно искать точку. callback на результат поиска не влияет, вам не нужен.